# Why isn't N2 a Lewis base?

Tags: acid-base

Why is $\ce{N2}$ (dinitrogen) not a Lewis base even with two lone pairs?

Answer (score 12):

Actually, it is, but a very weak one.

The lone electron pairs in dinitrogen are in $\mathrm{sp}$ hybridization state, and nitrogen is quite electronegative, so they are not easily donated. Still, if a Lewis acid is strong enough, dinitrogen may form a complex.

It is known that dinitrogen adsorbs on acidic $\ce{OH}$-groups in zeolites, forming complex with IR-active frequency. The nature of the complex may be debated, as no full proton transfer occurs, but the electron pairs are definitely involved.

[Diazonium salts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diazonium_compound) may be considered as a lewis-acid complex of a carbocation and dinitrogen molecule. While no direct synthetic route exists from dinitrogen to diazonium salt (because typically a stronger Lewis base is available), they typically decompose with formation of dinitrogen molecule.

Significant amount of [dinitrogen complexes with transition elements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transition_metal_dinitrogen_complex) are known. Typically they are obtained indirectly, by forming dinitrogen ligand in-place, though.

Finally, adsorption of dinitrogen on the surface of ammonia synthesis catalysts starts as a Lewis-interaction. Similarly, nitrogen adsorption on cations in zeolites is known.